# Is it recommended to have more than one NavController in Android Jetpack Compose Project?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am working on a project. It has multiple UI sections, for example:

1. Onboarding - it has 5 screens
2. Home screen with bottom navigation - it has 4 screens
3. Settings screen - it has 7 screens (destinations)

After on boarding, user lands on the home which has bottom navigation. Also the app has settings section with 7 destinations (like about screen, premium plans screen, etc.). I feel like I should create 3 nav controllers separately. Is it a recommended approach? Should I stick with one navigation controller throughout the app?

Comment: Yes, you can use nested navigation whenever it it required.

Comment: @ChiragThummar Thanks for the reply. My question is about using multiple nav controllers. Even in nested navigation, we can use one nav controller.